# ValueError: Expecting : delimiter:

Tags: python, json, json.net, jsonp

I am having trouble with this code: `CLIENT_ID = json.loads(open('var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/client_secrets .json','r').read())['web']['client_id']`

It came up as an error :ValueError: Expecting : delimiter: line 3 column 21 (char 34).

Then, I have read the other posts with similar issue and modfied the code by adding `r` like this example : `CLIENT_ID = json.loads(open(r'var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/client_secrets .json','r').read())['web']['client_id']`.

Unfortunately, I am getting the same error. How should I make the code to work without the same error again?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about R nor specific to ubuntu,

Comment: It is specific to UBUNTU, as I am creating a web server on ubuntu . I have linked my web page to the server, when it comes to working, the webpage stop working due to this error in my APPLICATION.PY. First, the client ID was the following: `CLIENT_ID = json.loads(open('client_secrets.json','r').read()) ['web']['client_id']`. then, the server came out with the error, **clients_secrets.json** not found. So, I have updated the client secret code and added the working directory of the **clients_secrets.json** which is the code that I presented you. Now, it says that there is a delimiter issue.

Comment: What is in the JSON file?  Is there a colon (or comma) missing on line 3?

Comment: yes, the issue has been solved, indeed, it was coming from the json file itself. there was something missing inside the file.